# Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined - Flutter web application release

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, uncaught-reference-error

I'm trying to release a flutter web application. It is working fine while running from the IDE or running on a local server (on python server/ Nginx etc) and also working fine even on firebase hosting.

When trying to deploy it as a containerized application on AWS and getting the following response while loading the application on the browser. Has anybody faced a similar kind of issue on release?

> GET https://url/flutter.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (index):46 Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined at (index):46:7 (anonymous) @ (index):46 load (async) (anonymous) @ (index):44 manifest.json:1 GET https://url/manifest.json 404 manifest.json:2 Manifest: Line: 2, column: 1, Syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I alse encountered this problem, here is the solution:

Edit **index.html**

Find the following Text:

```
<base href="/">
```

Change to this:

```
<base href="./">
```